# How can I add additional years to my dataset using multidplyr or parallel processing?

Tags: r, dplyr, parallel-processing, multidplyr

I have a dataset (*MN_Census*) that has information for all census tracts for the following years: 1990, 2000, 2010, and 2020. The variable ID that identifies the census tract is "*GISJOIN*". My dataset looks like this:

| GISJOIN | GEOGYEAR | STATE | STATEA | COUNTY | COUNTYA | TRACTA | CL8AA | CL9AA | DATAYEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G2700010770100 | 2010 | Minnesota | 27 | Aitkin County | 1 | 770100 | 1954.45 | 0 | 1990 |
| G2700010790502 | 2010 | Minnesota | 27 | Aitkin County | 1 | 790502 | 2045.99 | 0 | 1990 |
| G2700010770100 | 2010 | Minnesota | 27 | Aitkin County | 1 | 770100 | 2361.32 | 0 | 2000 |
| G2700010790502 | 2010 | Minnesota | 27 | Aitkin County | 1 | 790502 | 2862.97 | 0 | 2000 |
| G2700010770100 | 2010 | Minnesota | 27 | Aitkin County | 1 | 770100 | 2327 | 0 | 2010 |
| G2700010790502 | 2010 | Minnesota | 27 | Aitkin County | 1 | 790502 | 3262 | 0 | 2010 |
| G2700010770100 | 2010 | Minnesota | 27 | Aitkin County | 1 | 770100 | 2244 | NA | 2020 |
| G2700010790502 | 2010 | Minnesota | 27 | Aitkin County | 1 | 790502 | 3120 | NA | 2020 |

I'm trying to use either join/merge/rbind to add **foreach census tract**, the years in between. This is, I want to add the following dataset foreach of the census tract:

| YearTransaction |
| --- |
| 1990 |
| 1991 |
| 1992 |
| 1993 |
| 1994 |
| 1995 |
| 1996 |
| 1997 |
| 1998 |
| 1999 |
| 2000 |
| 2001 |
| 2002 |
| 2003 |
| 2004 |

So at the end, my desired dataset will have all years (from 1990 to 2020) foreach one of the census tract. I'm trying using "`multidplyr`" to make a partition by census tract ID (which is represented by the variable "*GISJOIN*"), and join each one of these partitions with the Years dataset. I'm using the following code:

```
library("parallel")
library("modeest")
library("multidplyr")
library("doParallel")
library("dtplyr")


detectCores()
cluster <- new_cluster(4)
base <- MN_Census %>% group_by(GISJOIN) %>% partition(cluster)
system.time(final <- dplyr::left_join(Years,base, by=c("YearTransaction"="DATAYEAR"),copy=TRUE) %>% collect())
final <- final %>% dplyr::ungroup()
```

However, I'm not getting the desired results. What I'm getting is a dataaset with all years (which is good), but these years are not duplicated foreach census tract (GISJOIN):
[image]

The desired dataset should look like this:

| DATAYEAR | GISJOIN | GEOGYEAR | STATE | STATEA | COUNTY | COUNTYA | TRACTA | CL8AA | CL9AA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1990 | G2700010770100 | 2010 | Minnesota | 27 | Aitkin County | 1 | 770100 | 1954.45 | 0 |
| 1991 | G2700010770100 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| … | G2700010770100 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2000 | G2700010770100 | 2010 | Minnesota | 27 | Aitkin County | 1 | 770100 | 2361.32 | 0 |
| 2001 | G2700010770100 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| … | G2700010770100 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2010 | G2700010770100 | 2010 | Minnesota | 27 | Aitkin County | 1 | 770100 | 2327 | 0 |
| 2011 | G2700010770100 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| … | G2700010770100 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2020 | G2700010770100 | 2010 | Minnesota | 27 | Aitkin County | 1 | 770100 | 2244 | NA |
| 1990 | G2700010790502 | 2010 | Minnesota | 27 | Aitkin County | 1 | 790502 | 2045.99 | 0 |
| 1991 | G2700010790502 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| … | G2700010790502 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2000 | G2700010790502 | 2010 | Minnesota | 27 | Aitkin County | 1 | 790502 | 2862.97 | 0 |
| 2001 | G2700010790502 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| … | G2700010790502 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2010 | G2700010790502 | 2010 | Minnesota | 27 | Aitkin County | 1 | 790502 | 3262 | 0 |
| 2011 | G2700010790502 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| … | G2700010790502 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2020 | G2700010790502 | 2010 | Minnesota | 27 | Aitkin County | 1 | 790502 | 3120 | NA |

How can I fix this using **multidplyr** or any kind of **parallel processing**? (My original dataset is huge).
**Any help using dplyr is really appreciated it!**

Comment: Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(TRACTA) %>% 
  tidyr::complete(DATAYEAR= full_seq(DATAYEAR, period = 1)) %>% 
  data.frame()
```

```
 TRACTA DATAYEAR              A GISJOIN  GEOGYEAR STATE STATEA COUNTY COUNTYA   CL8AA CL9AA
1  770100     1990 G2700010770100    2010 Minnesota    27 Aitkin County       1 1954.45     0
2  770100     1991           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
3  770100     1992           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
4  770100     1993           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
5  770100     1994           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
6  770100     1995           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
7  770100     1996           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
8  770100     1997           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
9  770100     1998           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
10 770100     1999           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
11 770100     2000 G2700010770100    2010 Minnesota    27 Aitkin County       1 2361.32     0
12 770100     2001           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
13 770100     2002           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
14 770100     2003           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
15 770100     2004           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
16 770100     2005           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
17 770100     2006           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
18 770100     2007           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
19 770100     2008           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
20 770100     2009           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
21 770100     2010 G2700010770100    2010 Minnesota    27 Aitkin County       1 2327.00     0
22 770100     2011           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
23 770100     2012           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
24 770100     2013           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
25 770100     2014           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
26 770100     2015           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
27 770100     2016           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
28 770100     2017           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
29 770100     2018           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
30 770100     2019           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
31 770100     2020 G2700010770100    2010 Minnesota    27 Aitkin County       1 2244.00    NA
32 790502     1990 G2700010790502    2010 Minnesota    27 Aitkin County       1 2045.99     0
33 790502     1991           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
34 790502     1992           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
35 790502     1993           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
36 790502     1994           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
37 790502     1995           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
38 790502     1996           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
39 790502     1997           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
40 790502     1998           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
41 790502     1999           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
42 790502     2000 G2700010790502    2010 Minnesota    27 Aitkin County       1 2862.97     0
43 790502     2001           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
44 790502     2002           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
45 790502     2003           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
46 790502     2004           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
47 790502     2005           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
48 790502     2006           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
49 790502     2007           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
50 790502     2008           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
51 790502     2009           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
52 790502     2010 G2700010790502    2010 Minnesota    27 Aitkin County       1 3262.00     0
53 790502     2011           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
54 790502     2012           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
55 790502     2013           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
56 790502     2014           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
57 790502     2015           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
58 790502     2016           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
59 790502     2017           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
60 790502     2018           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
61 790502     2019           <NA>      NA      <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
62 790502     2020 G2700010790502    2010 Minnesota    27 Aitkin County       1 3120.00    NA
```

Comment: Thanks @TarJae, however this doesn't give me the desired result. I want a database with each census tract containing information for 1990, 1991, etc. Could you please help me to  have this result?

Comment: You mean this `df %>% 
  tidyr::complete(DATAYEAR= full_seq(DATAYEAR, period = 1)) %>% 
  fill(-DATAYEAR, .direction = "down") %>% 
  data.frame()
` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried this but I only get the desired result for the second census tract (G2700010790502) instead of getting the results **also** for the other census tract (G2700010770100).

Comment: So you get the desired output?

Comment: No. Please see my response above.

Comment: Now it worked! Many thanks!! :) Does this work with parallel processing or multidplyr?